# From a list of string to hierarchical object

Tags: javascript, hierarchical-data

I am looking for a way to convert an array of string like:

```
['AABBCC','AABBDD','BBBBTT','BBVVDD']
```

Into an hierarchical json:

```
{
"code": "AA",
"sub": [
    {
        "code": "BB",
        "sub": [
            {
                "code": "CC"
            },
            {
                "code": "DD"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

And so on for BB element. The hierarchic is build using first 2 letters for the first group, then the other 2 for the second group.
Any idea on how to solve this problem?

Thanks a lot

Comment: What is the actual rule?

Comment: What have you tried?  What happened, and what did you want to happen instead?

Comment: Can you share any code that you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

This proposal features for the given array for iterating
 [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

> The `forEach()` method executes a provided function once per array element.

and for splitting the strings [`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

> The `match()` method retrieves the matches when matching a string against a regular expression.

and for the look up  [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

> The `some()` method tests whether some element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function.

If a `code` is found then the reference of `sub` is used for the next level.

If not, then a new object is pushed to the actual array.

```js
var data = ['AABBCC', 'AABBDD', 'BBBBTT', 'BBVVDD'],
    obj = [];

data.forEach(function (a) {
    var o = obj, keys = a.match(/.{1,2}/g);
    keys.forEach(function (k) {
        var oo = { code: k, sub: [] };
        if (!o.some(function (b) {
            if (b.code === k) {
                o = b.sub;
                return true;
            }
        })) {
            o.push(oo);
            o = oo.sub;
        }
    });
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(obj, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```